# user can click a link once at day

Tags: php

I have a table for users `users` and I have a page with (ex: 5 links)
if the user visits the page and click a link .. link should hide and user can't click it anymore.
Only one time per 24 hours ...

I tried with adding a column to my `users` table that store ids of the clicked links ... and ckeck every time the user visit the page of the links ... but it was complicated.

I have the jquery code for hiding the links when clicking it, but I think I should have a crone job.

I need advices and best way to do that (php)

Comment: cookies + checking ip + checking hw id with javascript (e.g: `fingerprintJS`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in PHP, by using Sessions - so basically you store a link id in the session that is either 0 or 1 depending on whether the user has clicked the link. Then when you load the page you check for that flag and hide the link using your javascript.

If the user has to be logged in to visit the page (it sounds that way as you have a user id), then you could store the session information with their user account info in the database. Then when they first login or access the page, the first thing you can do is check the session info.

Depending on whether or not you've used sessions before, there is a good tutorial here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

You could do something like this:

```
<?php
    // Start the session
    session_start();

   // Set session variables
   $_SESSION["link_id"] = $link_no;
   $_SESSION["timestamp"] = NOW();
 ?>
```

The first time they access the session you could check all the timestamps in the session info, and if more than 24 hours then reset the flag to 0.

Without seeing more of your code, it's difficult to answer more fully. I'd suggest setting up a jsfiddle or including more code details above.

Hope that helps!

EDIT

Yes you can store sessions in a database. This is a helpful tutorial:

http://culttt.com/2013/02/04/how-to-save-php-sessions-to-a-database/

In order to check whether the timestamp has expired I'd do the following.

1. User logs on
2. Pull previous/current session info from their account info.
3. Loop through session data and check whether any of the link timestamps exceeds 24 hours.
4. If the timestamps do exceed 24 hours reset that link flag to 0 - meaning that they can click the link.
5. Load the html page with links showing/not showing.

Comment: thanks for quick answer!
yes i use sessions before ... but can i store session in my db, i know how to store values but what about checking for 24 hours?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a tutorial for storing a session in a DB, and the process I'd go through to check the links. I wouldn't check once every 24 hours, a 24 hour period will be different for every user - so a user who clicks a link at 11.59pm and a user who clicks a link at 6am will have different reset times. If you just want it to reset at midnight, then you could set up a cron job to trigger a stored procedure which would delete all session data at midnight.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new table: **users_click_links** with 3 attributes: *user_id*, *link_id*, *last_click*.

When your PHP is going to render any page, check in this table if that *user_id* has an entry for that *link_id*. If they have, check the *last_click* datetime attribute of the row. If the difference with "now" is less than 24h, return a 404 (or whatever client error code you need to display). If it's okay, update *last_click* of the row. If it didn't exist, create it.

Same thing for every link that you need to render in the page. Check each of them and do not even render the text if they are not valid for the user. All validation should be done in the server side, you do not need to use jQuery for this problem of yours.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an `user` table. Now all you need to do is add a `link` table and connect the user clicks and links in `link_clicks` table. When the user clicks the appropriate link update the `last_clicked` field wit the timestamp.

```
links
----------
id    link
1      Link1
2      Link2
3      Link3
4      Link4

link_clicks
----------
id    user_id   link_id   last_clicked
1      101        3         {Timestamp}
```

Now each time you can check whether the user has clicked the link by comparing the current_time and the stored timestamp.

Comment: if any ideas helps you. please vote up that. It helps other people to get answer.